# Scratch org doesn't recognize my managed package

Tags: managed-package, scratch-org

I've built a 2nd generation managed package in a scratch org. All worked well but then when my scratch org expired and I spun up a new one, after uploading all my components to it again, I get messages indicating that my components can't be updated because they're part of a managed package. But it's MY managed package.

Is there something I need to do in order to keep it associated with my scratch orgs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To continue working on your second generation managed package, you need to make sure you follow the correct steps. First, you must have [linked your namespace](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_reg_namespace.htm) to the Dev Hub that you're using to create the scratch org. Second, you must have specified the `namespace` attribute in the [sfdx-project.json](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ws_config.htm) file before creating the scratch org. Third, you must upload your metadata with the [`project deploy start`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_project_commands_unified.htm#cli_reference_project_deploy_start_unified) command, and notably not the [`package install`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_package_commands_unified.htm#cli_reference_package_install_unified) command. The install command installs the package as a subscriber would, which means you can test the package's metadata to make sure it works, but you can't develop with it.

Comment: It was project deploy start that I was missing. Thanks!